# Can not load JSON after webpack: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, node.js, webpack

When I was using webpack-dev-server, everything works perfectly. 
But when deploying my application on a server with "webpack" command, I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
  at Object.parse (native)
  at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3389/bundle.js:24629:18)
  at XMLHttpRequest.respond (http://localhost:3389/bundle.js:24499:32)
```

I believe what I received is XML instead of JSON. I am not sure what to do with it. I am using request from 'd3-request' loading my JSON files. My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, './app'),
  entry: {
    js: './index.js',
    html: './index.html',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        ]
      },
      {
        // transpile es6/jsx code to es5
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }})
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './app',
    hot: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that preloader set up? Any particular reason?

Comment: I was trying to solve the problem. I saw others used this setting. It changed nothing.

Comment: Check out `bundle.js:24629:18` very carefully. Sometimes examining the resulting bundle helps with these.

Comment: You I tried to console.log the responseText of XMLHttpRequest. It turns out to be the whole code inside my index.html. That's why it starts with '<' and can't be parsed by JSON. Under develop mode, it logged out the content of JSON files as expected. I am totally confused.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest goes beyond webpack. Could it be something server related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the express code on the server side. I accidentally made Express get files from my index.html by a typo. Nothing wrong with webpack.